# Can ScrollController.jumpTo be overridden so that it does not interrupt a user's scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart

So it looks like by definition, a `jumpTo` will stop all user scrolls in progress:

`Any active animation is canceled. If the user is currently scrolling, that action is canceled.`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/jumpTo.html

Can this behavior be overwritten somehow?  I want to jump to certain parts of the list, but that may occur while a user is scrolling and they should be able to continue scrolling without lifting their finger and tapping to scroll again.

One catch is I'm using the PrimaryScrollController as my scrollcontroller:  `scrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);`

Comment: use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition/isScrollingNotifier.html to detect if the user is scrolling or not, if you detect active scroll action do not call `jumpTo`

Comment: @pskink I want to always do the jumpTo

Comment: so you could try to make a custom  `ScrollPosition` and override [jumpTo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b8f7f1f9869bb2d116aa6a70dbeac61000b52849/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart#L193), for more info check the docs for `ScrollPosition` (find "Subclassing ScrollPosition" section)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok for anyone else looking to an answer, I think I found it, never know it existed, but there's two things:

```
scrollController.position.correctBy(pixels); //Moves in some number forward or back relative to current position

scrollController.position.correctPixels(pixels); //Moves to some absolute position
```

Using these will do a jumpTo and the user scroll is not interrupted..

Comment: thank you so much. you literally saved my day.